# Effect Size for Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney in R Cohen's d

Tags: effect-size

I have a non-normal distribution data of two independent samples of patients divided by two groups 'control' and 'treatment'. I would like to verify if there is a difference between the two groups 'control' and 'treatment' and measure this difference, so I am using the code:

```
wilcox.test(data.to.work$disease ~ data.to.work$group)
```

Ok for my test, my doubt is: I can use Cohen's d to measure the effect size?

I also did a test using the codes:

```
cohens_d(data.to.work$disease ~ data.to.work$group)
rcompanion::wilcoxonR(data.to.work$disease, g=data.to.work$group, ci=T)
```

Both give large effect size.

May I use Cohen's d ? Or is the second test the most recommended, or some other?

Comment: See this duplicate post : [stackoverflow.com/questions/73166609/effect-size-for-wilcox-mann-whitney-in-r-cohens-d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73166609/effect-size-for-wilcox-mann-whitney-in-r-cohens-d)

Answer (score 3):

This is an exact duplicate of a post on Stack Exchange.  Here, I'll quote my answer from there.  [stackoverflow.com/questions/73166609/effect-size-for-wilcox-mann-whitney-in-r-cohens-d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73166609/effect-size-for-wilcox-mann-whitney-in-r-cohens-d)

> It would be unusual to pair Cohen's d with a Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney
> test. There's no reason that you couldn't calculate it, but probably,
> if you chose the WMW test, you wouldn't be that interested in
> comparing the difference in means of the samples to the pooled
> standard deviation.
>
> A typical standardized effect size statistic for the WMW test is based
> on the probability of an observation in one group being larger than an
> observation in the other group.
> These standardized effect size statistics include Vargha and Delaney’s A, Cliff’s delta, Glass rank biserial coefficient, and
> Grissom and Kim's Probability of Superiority.
> Rather than using the `wilcoxonR()` function, I would recommend using a different function in that package that calculates one of the
> effect size statistics mentioned above.